# java RMID example

Tags: java, rmi

I want to experiment with Activatable objects in RMI. Is there a simple example somewhere that works? I'm trying to use [Oracle's tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/activation.html) but I get java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:1098 connect,resolve)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this as first argument to your java-vm

```
-Djava.security.policy=rmi.security
```

example of rmi.security  (could be more specific, created with policytool)

```
grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```